# java HashMap sorting <String,Integer> . How to sort it?

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort a Map<Key, Value> on the values in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java)

In my project, I have taken a HashMap like this

> **HashMap degree = new HashMap();**

Suppose I have:

```
degree.put("a",5);
degree.put("b",2);
degree.put("c",4);
degree.put("d",2);
degree.put("e",3);
degree.put("f",5);
```

> Now I have to Sort this list according to given Integer values

Sorted HashMap Should be :

> **{a=5, f=5, c=4, e=4, b=4, d=2}**

*How I can do this ?*

Comment: Seems to me that the original HashMap sorted according to the integer values would in fact be like { a = 5, f = 5, c = 4, e = 3, b = 2, d = 2 }.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java

Answer (score 11):

A `HashMap` is an *unordered* collection. It has no sort order. Even a `TreeMap` will sort by key, not value.

If you want to prepare a sorted list by the sort order of the values, you'll have to create an appropriate object, such as an `ArrayList<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>`, iterate over your `HashMap` and insert all the entries, and then call `Collections.sort` with a collation function.

Answer (score 4):

If you want sorted map, HashMap isn't the best approach.

I'd suggest taking a look at `TreeMap` as it is sorted. You can set the comparator to compare the values instead of the keys, as they do in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1283722/975959

Comment: Better not plan on calling .get() on that TreeMap if it's looking at values.

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Integer> sortedHashMap=new ArrayList<Integer>();

for("your Object" m : degree.values())
{
      sortedHashMap.add(m);
}

collections.sort(sortedHashMap);
```

so ,you can print your hashMap as sorted hashMap!

Answer (score 0):

You can do [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) to build a new hashmap from the original(takes x2 memory and is very inefficient). So, you will need to use .get() and .set() methods of the hashmap nearly n*n(worst case) times where n is the number of elements.