# Make Map not print Fruits in arbitrary order, but in order of least to most expensive

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I am trying to create a class to represent a Fruit Store, and want to output the available fruit sorted by price, from least to most expensive. However, even though I add prices to my FruitPricesMap in the order of least expensive to most expensive it always prints the fruits in the same arbitrary order? How can I make it not do this?

****FruitStore.java****

```
import java.util.*;

public class FruitStore {

    private Map<String, Double> fruitPricesMap;

    public FruitStore() {
        fruitPricesMap = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public boolean addOrUpdateFruit(String fruitName, double fruitPrice) {
        fruitPricesMap.put(fruitName, fruitPrice);
        return true;
    }

    public void printAvaliableFruit() {
        System.out.println("Avaliable Fruit:");
        for (String key : fruitPricesMap.keySet()) {
            System.out.printf("%-15s  %.2f", key, fruitPricesMap.get(key));
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

****FruitStoreApp.java****

```
public class FruitStoreApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FruitStore fs = new FruitStore();
        fs.addOrUpdateFruit("Banana", 1.00);
        fs.addOrUpdateFruit("Apple", 2.00);
        fs.addOrUpdateFruit("Cherries", 3.00);
        fs.printAvaliableFruit();
    }

}
```

****Current output****

```
Avaliable Fruit:
Apple            2.00
Cherries         3.00
Banana           1.00
```

****Desired output (least expensive to most expensive):****

```
Avaliable Fruit:
Banana           1.00
Apple            2.00
Cherries         3.00
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting HashMap by values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119366/sorting-hashmap-by-values)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java HashMap sorting <String,Integer> . How to sort it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229577/java-hashmap-sorting-string-integer-how-to-sort-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a **[LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)**, and make sure to ensure to insert the fruits into the map in the order from least to most expensive since it maintains insertion order, unlike the regular **[HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)**.

I.e. Change the line:

```
fruitPricesMap = new HashMap<>();
```

to this:

```
fruitPricesMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) and specify the order you would like in a custom comparator.